# How to calculate time interval between current and voltage waveforms

Tags: ac

Is it basically, phase angle / angular frequency?

Also for a ac circuit with a single inductor is the phase angle going to be always 90degres, likewise with a circuit with a single capacitor?

Comment: Yes, where phase angle is in radians; and yes, 90 deg for C and for L.

Comment: Thanks, so (pie /2)/ angular frequency?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sinusoidal AC circuit, a useful term to remember is: -

C I V I L

- For a (C)apacitor I leads V.
- V leads I for an inductor (L)

In both cases, the leading/lagging is 90 degrees.

If the inductor or capacitor has resistive losses then the phase angle magnitude will be less than 90 degrees.

Comment: What about an ac circuit with a single resistor? Is the phase angle 0 in that case?

Comment: Yes it is @Nexus6

Comment: Thank you @Andy aka's

Comment: I am getting a complex infinity error when I enter into calculator,                    (pie/0)/150pie

Comment: "pie/0" = infinity

Comment: So the time interval for a series ac with a single resistor will always be 0?

Comment: The time difference between zero-crossing points of voltage and current for a pure resistor is zero. BTW I have no idea what *(pie/0)/150pie* is meant to represent (just in case you assume I do know).

Comment: Thanks Andy, last question. Is voltage leading the current in this situation?

Comment: Voltage leads current for an inductor.

Comment: And for juat a circuit with a single resistor?

Comment: As per my 2nd to last previous comment.